# React Native WebView: problems with displaying not mobile-friendly sites

Tags: android, webview, react-native

I am using this simple app

```
var WebViewTest = React.createClass({
  render:function() {
    console.log(this.refs)
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <WebView
            scalesPageToFit={false}
            ref='webView'
            source={{uri: 'http://company_website.com'}}
          />
        <View
          style={{justifyContent:'space-between',flexDirection:'row',alignSelf:'flex-end',marginBottom:0}}>
            <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center'}} onPress={this.navigateBack}>
              <Text>back</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <TouchableHighlight style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center'}} onPress={this.navigateForward}>
              <Text>forward</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  },
  navigateBack:function(){
    this.refs.webView.goBack()
  },
  navigateForward:function(){
    this.refs.webView.goForward()
  },
})
```

And I want it to display the website like chrome does

[image: chrome rendering]

but the webview shows it only like this

[image: my rendering]

The website I'm trying to render is not yet built for phones.

Why does WebView render the website so differently? how to get it to behave?

Comment: I would assume, it is `scalesPageToFit={false}` - Chrome seems to scale the page down to fit if it is not responsive. Set it to true.

Comment: changing that prop doesn't affect the result unfortunately

Comment: Does it renders another website?

Comment: Facebook, Wikipedia and other mobile.friendly sites are rendered correctly.

Comment: @Zygro did you find a solution? I'm experiencing the same, it works well on some web sites but it seems to crush on others but no error triggered.

Comment: There was a problem with the website. After some days the web guys fixed it, but I didn't work on that so I don't know what happened.

Comment: @christian prefect answer thank you